# Can you invoke the same useState hook within the same function more than once?

Tags: reactjs, dialogflow-es, react-hooks, chatbot, use-state

So amidst refactoring my class based chatbot component to use react hooks I came across a problem with the useState hook overwriting the object in the state. This lead to only the bot responses showing up in the UI. When I chat with the bot, a flash of the user input shows in the UI then is overwritten by the chatbots response. Here is the code:

```
export const Chatbot = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  async function df_text_query(text) {
    let says = {
      speaks: "me",
      message: {
        text: {
          text
        }
      }
    };
    setMessages([...messages, says]);

    const res = await axios.post("/api/df_text_query", {
      text,
      userID: cookies.get("userID")
    });

    // Handles fullfillment routes for dialogflow
    res.data.fulfillmentMessages.forEach(message => {
      says = {
        speaks: "bot",
        message
      };
      setMessages([...messages, says]);
    });
  }

  const handleChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (value !== "") {
      const message = value.split();
      df_text_query(message);
    }
    setValue("");
  };

  const handleButtonSend = async event => {
    const eventText = event.target.innerText;
    await setValue(eventText);
    const message = value.split();
    await df_text_query(message);
    await setValue("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>chatbot code here</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Is it possible to write useState like this, twice within the same async function? 
If not how do you propose I refactor this code so that the messages state returns an array of alternating objects such as:

````
[{says: {
   speaks: "me",
   message: {
       text: {
          text
       }
    }
  }
},
{says: {
   speaks: "bot",
   message: {
      text: {
        text
      }
     }
   }
 },
{says: {
   speaks: "me",
   message: {
       text: {
          text
       }
    }
  }
},
{says: {
   speaks: "bot",
   message: {
      text: {
        text
      }
     }
   }
 }
]```

Any answer would be very much appreciated. I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. If you need more information I'm happy to provide!

Cheers,

Jacks
````

Comment: Yeah because state setting is async, the second `setMessages()` call is still using the old state, so it overwrites the one you just added. Simplest way would be to save the message objects in variables, then append them both at the same time in *one* `setMessages()` call. It's more efficient too, since it'll only lead to 1 re-render, instead of 2

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! I'll go ahead and try that.

Comment: It overwrites that and renders twice, so you never get to see the first value. By the time it renders as its async, the value is overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
 async function df_text_query(text) {
    let says = [{
      speaks: "me",
      message: {
        text: {
          text
        }
      }
    }];

    const res = await axios.post("/api/df_text_query", {
      text,
      userID: cookies.get("userID")
    });

    // Handles fullfillment routes for dialogflow
    let saysBatch = [says, ...res.data.fulfillmentMessages.map(message => ({
        speaks: "bot",
        message
      }))];
    setMessages([...messages, ...saysBatch]);
```